# .NET 4.0 migration error: Culture is not supported

Tags: .net-4.0, cultureinfo

We have migrated our web applications and services from .NET 2.0 to .NET 4.0. Since then I am getting the below exception on one of the screens.

This error is at this line of code:

```
obj.name = sqldatareader["name"].ToString()
```

There are similar `sqldatareader`s used in other parts of code which works fine.

Additional information:

1. Version information: Microsoft .NET Framework version: 4.0.30319, IIS 7.5, win 2012 r2.
2. Regional settings are set correctly on the web servers (to Japanese)
   Any pointers on this issue would be helpful.

Error:

> General Information
>
> ---
>
> Additional Info:
>
> MessageDetails: Exception Details: System.Exception --->
>   System.Exception ---> System.Globalization.CultureNotFoundException:
>   Culture is not supported.
>
> Parameter name: culture
>
> 66577 (0x10411) is an invalid culture identifier.
>
> at System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(Int32 culture)
>
> at System.Globalization.CompareInfo.GetCompareInfo(Int32 culture)
>
> at System.Data.ProviderBase.FieldNameLookup.LinearIndexOf(String
>   fieldName, CompareOptions compareOptions)
>
> at System.Data.ProviderBase.FieldNameLookup.IndexOf(String
>   fieldName)
>
> at System.Data.ProviderBase.FieldNameLookup.GetOrdinal(String
>   fieldName)
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetOrdinal(String name)
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_Item(String name)

Comment: 0x10411 is an odd-ball LCID, it has something to do with "Japanese Unicode".  Mentioned in [this blog post](http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2008/05/07/8464448.html).  Mitch's blog posts are always hard to parse, the only thing I get from it is that it selects an unusual sorting order and that it was kept around too long.  .NET 4 does matter, it now uses the operating system settings for culture.  serverfault.com ought to be the best place to find out what setting on the server you need to change.